6-Speed SIS Index Gearbox Shifting not Accessing Some Intermediate Cogs
I have a 6 speed SIS Index transmission.  In higher performances it works normally.  But in the lower I have a problem.  It does not shift back from 6 to 5. But I can shift to 4 and 3, but then again it does not go to 2 but only to 1. This means that I can shift from 6 to 4, 3 and 1 in the lower ones.

Welcome to the site - Could you please add some photos of your derailleur and cassette with [edit] ?  At this time I'd suspect Dirt or Wear or a stretched inner cable, or maybe the wrong shifter.  There's also a chance the hanger/rear derailleur is bent.
